# Does Dropbox interface with another version control system behind the scenes?

Tags: dropbox

For projects where I'm working alone Dropbox serves as a sweet and simple version control system. Occasionally I will decide to share the project with a collaborator and then I will want a little more control of how the version control is managed.

It would be awesome to be able to export a dropbox folder and it's history to a Git or SVN repository in these situations. This is not an option now (as far as I know), but I am curious:

Does anyone know if Dropbox is already built on top of one of these systems?

If so, what level of access does one have to the version control system from the API (or otherwise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Dropbox presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/VivekKantariya/dropbox-9444207) (slide 12):

> The software does not use any third-party file sync or version control
>   libraries.

Dropbox wouldn't make for a very robust source control system for more than one user - it doesn't handle merging and lacks functions such as diff. You may want to have a look at using something like Git with Dropbox if you do really want to use that for sharing your code.